# Differential equation of the NPN transistor configured as a voltage divider

Tags: transistors, differential, equation

The mathematical model in AC of the NPN transistor is represented by the pi model which is only one resistance in parallel to the resistors of the divider and the DC source in parallel to the collector resistance and the resistance of the load. How could you get the differential equation? Thank you very much in advance for your answer

Comment: "The" mathematical model is really just naivety. Draw a picture or show an image if you want a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Marie --- a emttier resistor and a collector resistor **MAY** approximately set the gain, if

- beta is high

- Vce >> 0 volts (perhaps 1-10 volts, but well out of saturation)

Examine the maths, perturb (introduce tiny changes) the voltages, and extract WHY

Rc/Re

is a good predictor.